# Dart calling native C code - Failed to lookup symbol

Tags: ios, c, xcode, dart, ffi

I am trying to include this library https://github.com/pganalyze/libpg_query in my Flutter app. I pulled the library code, built it, and then placed it inside XCode. I followed and applied the Source code and Stripping iOS Symbols paragraphs from the official docs https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/c-interop

I generated the dart ffi bindings from the pg_query.h file and then try to load the lib with `DynamicLibrary.process();`. Everything seems to be working, I am calling only one function, and it seems to be working. I uploaded it to TestFlight, and tried the release build. It's all good. I release the app and all users that try it have this crash `Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'pg_query_split_with_parser': dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, pg_query_split_with_parser): symbol not found` . I deleted my test flight app and installed it from the App Store, and everything works. What did I miss?